# Automatically set S3 bucket to host

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I have been using ASP.NET C# and managed to create a bucket and upload the files to the S3 bucket through the server-side code. However, I still need the bucket to automatically allow static hosting without the need to go manually and click the button allow static hosting at the AWS website. Is it possible to do so with asp.net C# code or maybe other features at AWS website?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: This question doesn't relate to ASP.NET so I've removed that tag.

Comment: It seems like you're looking for [this `PutBucketWebsite` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketWebsite.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. From the page that you suggested me I found another link that can help me which is AWS SDK for .NET which consists of the code needed. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=S3/